# Как узнать последний символ строки в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать последний символ определенной строки списка.
Например, дан список `list = ["aaab","aade","abez"]`
Как вывести последний символ элемента `list[0]`, чтобы получилось `b`

То есть мне нужна конструкция по аналогии с Java `list[0].charAt(list[0].length()-1)`

Comment: так: `list[0][-1]`. PS не используйте зарезервированные слова в качестве имен переменных - после этого вы не сможете восполоьзоваться конструктором `list()`...

Comment: Да, `list` я использовал для примера. Спасибо большое за ответ, пробовал подобный вариант но с -1 не рассмотрел, затупил. А ради интереса, возможно как-то взять элемент отличный от 0 или -1? Ну например из середины

Comment: Вы можете выбрать любой элемент из списка в диапазоне: `[0, len(list_)-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой и красивый способ -- обращение по отрицательному индексу, который помогает получать элементы в обратном порядке:

- `-1` -- последний элемент
- `-2` -- предпоследний элемент
- ...

Пример:

```
items = ["aaab", "aade", "abez"]
print(items[0][-1])
# b

print(items[0][len(items[0]) - 1])
# b

for x in items:
    print(x, x[-1], x[-2], x[-3], x[-4], sep=' | ')

# aaab | b | a | a | a
# aade | e | d | a | a
# abez | z | e | b | a
```

Comment: `[last for *_, last in items]` А так не покрасивше будет? Если речь идет о последнем символе?

Comment: @Namerek, тогда уж: `[last for *_, last in items][0]`, сравните с `items[0][-1]` :)

Comment: Если говорить об "определенной строке" то да

Comment: @Namerek, ок, если для всех, то `[item[-1] for item in items]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
stroke = ['asd','','']
print([i for i in stroke[0][::-1]][0])
```